# zsh: Disable "file exists:" warning with redirection

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

How can I override the `file exists:` warning from zsh?

```
> echo > newfile.txt
> echo > newfile.txt  
zsh: file exists: newfile.txt
```

In these cases I prefer my shell to not complain and simply overwrite the file, like bash.

Likewise, how to override the following:

```
$ ls >> /tmp/testfile.txt                                                                                                                                                   
zsh: no such file or directory: /tmp/testfile.txt
```

Comment: `set +C` should be longer for a comment. But maybe that's because i failed to mention `>|` for a single-use case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Does your `setopt` output mention `noclobber`? If so, that's it, just `setopt clobber`

The documentation for the option is at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-file-clobbering_002c-allowing

Answer (score 66):

You can force the ZSH to [clobber on redirect](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) with:

```
>!
```

> Same as >, except that the file is truncated to zero length if it exists, even if CLOBBER is unset.

or

```
>>!
```

> Same as >>, except that the file is created if it does not exist, even if CLOBBER is unset.

Answer (score 27):

Others have recommended using `>!` or `>>!` but these are not POSIX standard. The POSIx compliant way to overwrite files without prompting is to use `>|` or `>>|` and this will work in *any* shell.

For information see here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02

Comment: Note that the `noclobber` feature comes from csh, long before it was added to the Bourne shell or POSIX. And the syntax there was and still is with `>!`. In the `fish` shell, neither `>!` nor `>|` are supported. The former will redirect stdout to a `!` file, and `>|` will give you a syntax error. Same in `rc` and derivatives.