# posix standard to overwrite redirection causes unexpected output

Tags: bash, zsh, io-redirection

I've been trying to build a small bash script to override some configuration in Node. I'm using zsh, so there's a warning if you redirect output in an existing file ([see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212127/zsh-disable-file-exists-warning-with-redirection)). I've been trying the proposed answer, although the output is quite unusual. I was wondering maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

```bsh
echo 'module.exports = { "foo": 1 }' > foo.js

node -e '
  const foo = require("./foo")
  foo.bar = 1
  console.log(`module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(foo)}`)
'

# output is: module.exports = {"foo":1,"bar":1}

node -e '
  const foo = require("./foo")
  foo.bar = 1
  console.log(`module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(foo)}`)
' > bar.js

cat bar.js

# output is: module.exports = {"foo":1,"bar":1}

node -e '
  const foo = require("./foo")
  foo.bar = 1
  console.log(`module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(foo)}`)
' >| foo.js

# output is: module.exports = {"bar":1}
```

I was under the impression that `>|` would bypass the "overwrite file" warning from zsh, but it does compute a "different than expected" return value.

Actual: `module.exports = {"bar":1}`
Expected: `module.exports = {"foo":1,"bar":1}`

Where have gone the bytes of `"foo:1"`? Could somebody explain me what's happening?

Comment: What is the issue? Could you point out what you think is unusual? Also, are you using `bash` or `zsh` (you mention both)?  Note that redirections are carried out _before_ the command is executed. If the redirection truncates the file, it is truncated when the command runs.

Comment: @Kusalananda i'm sorry if i didn't make the outcome clear enough. let me edit/add some  expectations there so you get a better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the output of a command is redirected with `>` or `>|` to a file, that file is first truncated (emptied), *then* the command is executed.

When you run your Node.js code in the last example, the file `foo.js` is empty, due to to redirection.  This is why the original data from that file is not visible in the output.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense! thank you :)